# How to display content of single html in two frames

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to HTML. I have a html contains table and a group of div's. Each div represents some data related to each row. Scenario: When i click on any of the table row, I should display respective div content. I am able to display the respective div content in a column of the table(in front of respective row). But I want to display div content in separate frame. Is this possible to display Main table in 1 frame and clicking on each row, respective div details in other frame ?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function toggle(d, link){ 
  var e=document.getElementById(d);
  if (e.style.display == ''){
     e.style.display = 'none'; link.innerHTML = '[+]';
  } else {
     e.style.display = '';link.innerHTML = '[-]';
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Result_Details"><table id="resultDetails" border=1><th colspan="3">Result Details</th>
<tr class="collapse">
  <td width="4%">XYZ</td>
  <td>Item 1</td>
  <td><a href="#" onclick="toggle('Node_Details0', this)">more...</a>
  <div id="Node_Details0" style="display: none">
    <table border=1><tbody><th colspan=3>IT Details</big></th><tr><td><b>Foo</b></td></table>
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the code and someone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/NTFb2/2/

Not sure where is your respective div content.

I assume your table and div like this. (may be only one div)

## HTML

```
<div id="frame1">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>1
                <div class="content">Contents of row 1</div>
            </td>
            <td>1
                <div class="content">Contents of row 1</div>
            </td>
            <td>1
                <div class="content">Contents of row 1</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2
                <div class="content">Contents of row 2</div>
            </td>
            <td>2
                <div class="content">Contents of row 2</div>
            </td>
            <td>2
                <div class="content">Contents of row 2</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3
                <div class="content">Contents of row 3</div>
            </td>
            <td>3
                <div class="content">Contents of row 3</div>
            </td>
            <td>3
                <div class="content">Contents of row 3</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="frame2">
    <div id="showContent"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#frame1{float:left;width:100%;height:150px;overflow:auto;}
#frame2{float:left;width:100%;height:auto;overflow:auto;margin-top:10px;}
table {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
table .content {
    visibility:hidden;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
}
#showContent {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').on('click',function(){
        $('#showContent').html($(this).find('.content').html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, out put should be something as shown in demo. But i want it in separate frame. As my html can contain more than 1000 rows, and if we display row details in separate frame, it will be great.

Comment: check my update answer again, http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/NTFb2/2/
... I splid 2 frames, top 50% and bottom 50%, your table rows can be viewed by scrolling, and also content can be seen by clicking on the row.

Comment: I am seeing one more issue with using these frames, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691370/jquery-is-not-working-on-different-frame#comment25777820_17691370 . Could you please look into this post.